# Passar um valor indeterminado de um input para Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Já vi bastante perguntas parecidas mas nenhuma que resolvesse meu problema. O script basicamente é o seguinte, existem 3 inputs, e os valores dos inputs quem vai dizer é o usuário (o usuário irá fazer a média de suas notas). No script estou usando prompt para declarar os valores, mas quero que os valores sejam digitados em Inputs na página.

```
Javascript:

function verNota(){

    var nota_1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite sua primeira nota:"));
    var nota_2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite sua segunda nota:"));
    var nota_3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite sua terceira nota:"));

    var nota_parcial = (nota_1 + nota_2 + nota_3) / 3;

if (nota_parcial < 5){
    if(nota_1 == nota_2 && nota_1 == nota_3){
        nota_4 = 15 - nota_2 - nota_3;
    }
    if(nota_1 < nota_2 && nota_1 < nota_3){
        nota_4 = 15 - nota_2 - nota_3;
    }
    if(nota_2 < nota_1 && nota_2 < nota_3){
        nota_4 = 15 - nota_1 - nota_3;
    }
    if(nota_3 < nota_1 && nota_3 < nota_2){
        nota_4 = 15 - nota_1 - nota_2;
    }
    if(nota_parcial < 3){
        alert("Sua nota é: " + nota_parcial + ". Você está reprovado!")
    }
    else{
        alert("Sua nota é: " + nota_parcial + ". Você está parcialmente reprovado.");
        alert("Para ser aprovado você precisa tirar: " + nota_4 + " na quarta prova!");
    }
}
if (nota_parcial >= 5){
    alert("Sua nota é " + nota_parcial + ". Você está aprovado!");
}
}


HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="number" id="nota_1">
    <input type="number" id="nota_2">
    <input type="number" id="nota_3">

    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="verNota()" value="Testar Notas">

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então, para você pegar os valores pelos `input`, é só pegar os elementos através de um **id** por exemplo e assim pegar seus valores, faltou declarar tbm a variável **`nota_4`**. Acredito que esteja aprendendo Javascript, um bom exercício agora para você seria trocar este monte de **if** por um [switch-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) talvez:

```js
function verNota() {

  var nota_1 = document.getElementById('nota_1').value;
  var nota_2 = document.getElementById('nota_2').value;
  var nota_3 = document.getElementById('nota_3').value;
  var nota_4;

  var nota_parcial = parseFloat(nota_1) + parseFloat(nota_2) + parseFloat(nota_3) / 3;

  if (nota_parcial < 5) {
    if (nota_1 == nota_2 && nota_1 == nota_3) nota_4 = 15 - nota_2 - nota_3;
    if (nota_1 < nota_2 && nota_1 < nota_3) nota_4 = 15 - nota_2 - nota_3;
    if (nota_2 < nota_1 && nota_2 < nota_3) nota_4 = 15 - nota_1 - nota_3;
    if (nota_3 < nota_1 && nota_3 < nota_2) nota_4 = 15 - nota_1 - nota_2;
    if (nota_parcial < 3) alert("Sua nota é: " + nota_parcial + ". Você está reprovado!")
    else {
      alert("Sua nota é: " + nota_parcial + ". Você está parcialmente reprovado.");
      alert("Para ser aprovado você precisa tirar: " + nota_4 + " na quarta prova!");
    }
  }
  if (nota_parcial >= 5) alert("Sua nota é " + nota_parcial + ". Você está aprovado!");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="nota_1">
<input type="number" id="nota_2">
<input type="number" id="nota_3">

<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="verNota()" value="Testar Notas">
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda! Só tem uma coisa que não sei se você esqueceu ou passou despercebido. Na var da nota_parcial, todos os parseFloat devem estar entre parentese, pois o 3 está dividindo apenas o parseFloat(nota_3). Eu observei mas ja fiz as devidas alterações. Mais uma vez obrigado!